# Multiple Web Components for one Project, Visual Studio

Tags: lightning-web-components, visualstudiocode

When attempting to create multiple Web Components through VSCode, do you have to create multiple projects, or can you have one project with multiple components?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one project for all your components, if you desire, or you can break them up in to multiple projects (e.g. for organization purposes). It would probably be easier to simply have one project, however, with a separate directory for each package. You might want to check out the [dreamhouse-lwc](https://github.com/dreamhouseapp/dreamhouse-lwc) package on GitHub for a sample.

Comment: Hmm, So when I tried to add another component to my project (the second component) and then tried to deploy to my organization, only my first component showed up in SF, not both?

Comment: @BlondeSwan You may have simply deployed it wrong? Try right-clicking on the missing lwc component in VS Code and choose "Deploy to Org".

Answer (score 1):

A project in your VS Code usually maps to the components in your Org. So as long as you are building it for the same Org, you should always try to keep any components built in the same project in VS Code.

It's just the representation of the components which are a component bundle for aura and web components where each component is stored in their respective folders as compared to say apex classes or VF page, which are stored in `/classes` or `/pages` folders.

As an example this is how components from my personal DE looks like in VS Code:
 [image]

And when I need to deploy a component, I just deploy either the whole component folder or individual component.